# Filter message in event receiver WSO2

Tags: wso2

I have recently started with WSO2 CEP. connected to a topic where many messages pass, but suppose I just want to get the messages of a type, for example all messages that have type TT -> {"name": " hello "," type ":" TT "}, I have seen that the messageSelector can be used but I do not know how to use it. An example->  type: 'TT'
I do not know if I'm treating him well since the ones are json.

Sorry for the English ;).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the messageSelector parameter as follows in the receiver configurations?

```
<property name="transport.jms.MessageSelector">type='TT'</property>
```

Comment: Yes, I get the following error:  To property transport.jms.MessageSelector with value $.type='RTG' is dropped as its irrelevant of input adapter type:jms

Comment: Which version of CEP are you using?

Comment: CEP  version 4.2.0